# Rails - speed and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, highcharts

I have a question about the "speed of logic" between MVC.
Suppose to have the same code, something like the follow, in a model, in a view and in a controller.

1) The speed for "compiling" the logic and the query is the same in all three (M-V-C)?

Pseudocode

```
x = model.where(:a > 3, b < 9).a.first
y = model.sum(:a)
z = (x / y) * 2310.0
Date.today - 5
```

This is a "stupid" pseudocode, but I want to know the performance of line of code most used by my app (calling a `where` query, calling a `sum` (aggregate) query, do some math, playing with date)

The problem, is that my pages are a bit so slowly to load. I have deplaced all that manage queries in the `Models` and add indexes. Maybe adding the caching can solve a little the problem (but I use Highcharts that I think can't be cached).

2) How can I find where is the code bottleneck (that slow the loading of pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some known tools to profile your controllers/actions/views/models.

1. NewRelic (a good agent to track your time in distributed manner..I'd prefer this one)
2. Librato (An agent to which you can pass on your metrics whenever a controller/action is hit and it can give you a result over a period of time)
3. Rails console outputs the distribution of time spent in controller, views and active record. You can definitely track some good things here. (Please see the attached screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the complete question! I think I will begin to play with NewRelic.